# FBSDKCoreKit cocoapod compilation fails

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, cocoapods, fbsdk

I installed the new cocoapods version 1.0.2 today (it was 0.39 before) and since then the compilation of FBSDKCoreKit fails with the following error:

> 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCopying.h' file not found
>   Could not build Objective-C module 'FBSDKCoreKit'

The line where it happens is the following:

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCopying.h>
```

I am using Swift and cleaning and building again does not work as well as running `pod install` again. If I look inside the FBSDKCoreKit folder, there is actually a `FBSDKCopying.h` file.

Is this error cocoapods related or FBSDK related? Do you know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Try to close Xcode and then in the project folder delete Build and Pods folders and the .xcworkspace file.

Then run `pod install` from Terminal to recreate the workspace.

This fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. remove all files in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
2. delete all folders in /YourProject/Build/Products/

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this error today, so I will dig this despite over 3 years passed.

In Xcode:
For all targets and project I've changed "Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)" in "Build Settings" to true ('Yes').
In Podfile:
I've changed '~>5.2' to '5.8.0' (and followed with pod install), that forced my project to use FBSDK v5.8.0 instead of v5.14.0 and finally after few hours of cursing Zuckerberg's name I've managed to build Example project :]